# Do Django models have a data dict containing all the current values?

Tags: python, django, django-models

Something like

```
my_model.data_dict['my_field']
```

Which would give you the current value for that field? Need something like that to interface with my other code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may also want to have a look at the values method on the queryset. It will return dictionaries for any query instead of the usual model instances.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/ref/models/querysets/#values

(from docs)

```
>>> Blog.objects.filter(name__startswith='Beatles').values()
[{'id': 1, 'name': 'Beatles Blog', 'tagline': 'All the latest Beatles news.'}]
```

Comment: I don't remember what I needed this for any more.... I may have needed to turn it into a dict after I already fetched it....but if not, this looks like it would be the way to go.

Answer (score 1):

It's lil tricky but you can do it like this:

```
def model2dict(obj):
   return dict([(field, getattr(obj, field)) for field in obj._meta.get_all_field_names()])
```

So you can access values:

```
model2dict(my_model)['my_field']
```

Comment: Does that mean "no, they don't such an attribute"?

Comment: Oops..I butchered that sentence. Should read "No, they don't have such an attribute" -- i.e., a dict attribute containing all the values. But I think you figured that out :)

Comment: @Marcin: Yes. If that will give access to the actual values and not the `CharField` objects, then that would work as well. I think Jeremy's solution is cleaner though. Again, I have no idea what I was trying to accomplish with this anymore though. Was 2 years ago :D

Answer (score 1):

They have a `__dict__` property (which is a standard property): `my_model.__dict__['my_field']`

However, the standard way of doing this sort of access is with `getattr`: `getattr(my_model, 'my_field')`.

See: http://docs.python.org/reference/datamodel.html#new-style-and-classic-classes. Also look up `__slots__` to understand about classes that don't have this property.

As Jeremy notes above, anyone looking for this with django may like to also consider using `queryset.values()` ( https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#values ).